# Regex to remove \u00A0

Tags: regex

I have some text and would like to capture what is after the `-`. The issue that I am encountering is that I am returning lots of `\u00A0` and I'm unsure how to remove these so I just capture the clean text.

```
SQL Agent Job(?<sql_agent_job>[^.\n]*)
```

Text:

```
Server                 - HO-MysqlConnection
SQL Agent Job          - Targets
Procedure              - usp_DailyRun
```

Output that I am currently getting:

```
"sql_agent_job":"Targets\u00A0Procedure\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0 - usp_DailyRun
```

https://regex101.com/r/DCUAcw/1

Comment: They are space characters, which appear to show up as encoded entities when you encode the found text to JSON…?!

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: So, remove them, `.replace("\xA0", "")`

Comment: Thanks :) Is there no way to do this with the expression? So we can capture after the dash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```php
SQL Agent Job[^\S\r\n]*-[^\S\r\n]*(?<date>.+)
```

See [proof](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=SQL+Agent+Job%5b%5e%5cS%5cr%5cn%5d*-%5b%5e%5cS%5cr%5cn%5d*%28%3f%3cdate%3e.%2b%29&i=Server+++++++++++++++++-+mysqlConnection%0d%0aSQL+Agent+Job++++++++++-+Targets%0d%0aProcedure++++++++++++++-+DailyRun).

**Explanation**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  SQL Agent Job            'SQL Agent Job'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^\S\r\n]*               any character except: non-whitespace (all
                           but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " "), '\r'
                           (carriage return), '\n' (newline) (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^\S\r\n]*               any character except: non-whitespace (all
                           but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " "), '\r'
                           (carriage return), '\n' (newline) (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although this works in regex101, I'm getting an error when running it in .net. Would you know how to alter it to deal with this? Sorry, new to regex. `System.Text.RegularExpressions: Invalid pattern 'SQL Agent Job\h*-\h*(?<sql_agent_job>)' at offset 15. Unrecognized escape sequence \\h.`

Comment: @Greg Apologies, I had no idea this is a C# question. Use an updated regex, and [here is the  .NET regex proof](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=SQL+Agent+Job%5b%5e%5cS%5cr%5cn%5d*-%5b%5e%5cS%5cr%5cn%5d*%28%3f%3cdate%3e.%2b%29&i=Server+++++++++++++++++-+mysqlConnection%0d%0aSQL+Agent+Job++++++++++-+Targets%0d%0aProcedure++++++++++++++-+DailyRun).